# Oracle With Arithmetic Operators

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

How do i not allow use for arithmetic operators in specific columns in Oracle DWH?

Users mustn't this usage:

```
SELECT id, customername FROM customers WHERE id = 10+5
```

OR

```
SELECT id, customername FROM customers WHERE id = '1'+'5'
```

OR

```
SELECT id, customername FROM customers WHERE id = '1' || '5'
```

Users must be use this style :

```
SELECT id, customername FROM customers WHERE id = 15
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to police all SQL, or is there an interface where you can check user-supplied parameter values? Also, why? `10+5` is the same as `15`.

Comment: You can't prohibit some expression but not others. But you can "hide" your tables and only allow PL/SQL to return table data.

Comment: I have some keywords and checking users scripts with this keywords but some users using this style so we can’t catch used keywords. In fact , 10+5 is same as 15 but I can catch 15 ))

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? It sounds like you're trying to limit users' access to data by intercepting query parameters - instead of using [built-in database controls](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/part_3.html)?

Comment: Agree with Alex. This seems like a good use for Virtual Private Database, because you *can't* realistically filter every possible SQL expression.

Comment: I work for a company with more than 10,000 employees. We need to control database usage within the company, we have an estimated 5,000 keywords. If these keywords are used in queries, we check whether the relevant queries are for business or personal use. However, some users mislead these keywords through arithmetic operators and write them as 10+5 instead of 15 as I mentioned in the example above. Since our keyword is 15, it cannot catch the 10+5 query. This is the root of our problem :)

Comment: There's no any difference for Oracle between 15 and 10+5. You need to restrict allowed operations in the front end. Invalid operations will be rejected by the parser. Looks like you are trying to implement auditing instead of [existing functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html). As you may see, this may be hacked by equivalent expressions (e.g. `'a' || 'b'` instead of `'ab'`)

Comment: how can i do that? "You need to restrict allowed operations in the front end. Invalid operations will be rejected by the parser."

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how `15` can be a keyword. And I don't think you answered my question about interfaces. Do you want to create some kind of database trigger that causes any non-compliant SQL to fail, or can you catch user-written queries in a front-end application?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `id` column be an integer, you have to compare it against either an integer literal, integer column, or some other expression whose result evalautes to an integer.  Your current version:

```sql
SELECT id, customername FROM customers WHERE id = '1' || '5'
```

can be made to work by casting to integer with `TO_NUMBER()`:

```sql
SELECT id, customername FROM customers WHERE id = TO_NUMBER('1' || '5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bind parameters:

```sql
SELECT id, customername FROM customers WHERE id = :v_id;
```

Then the user can specify the value of the bind variable `:v_id` using whatever front-end interface you are using and it can only be a single value such as `15` or a single string `'10+5'` (which is a single scalar string value containing the characters `1` then `0` then `+` then `5` and will not be evaluated as a numeric operation).